# mysql: sum data based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, left-join

I have multiple tables where they are linked by NAME.

```
Table PlayerDetails:

PlayerName | Gender | Grade
Mike       | Male   | 3rd
Brian      | Male   | 4th
Audrey     | Female | 3rd
Karen      | Female | 5th
Steve      | Male   | 4th


Table PlayerEval:
PlayerName | Skill-1 | Skill-2 | Skill-3 | Year
Mike       |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2014
Mike       |   3.5   |    1    |   2     | 2014
Mike       |         |    1    |         | 2014
Brian      |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2014
Karen      |   3     |         |   4     | 2014
Karen      |         |    2    |   4     | 2014
Audrey     |   3     |    2    |         | 2013
Mike       |         |    2    |   4     | 2013


Table CoachEval:
PlayerName | Skill-1 | Skill-2 | Skill-3 | Year
Mike       |   2     |    1    |   3     | 2014
Brian      |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2014
Karen      |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2014
Karen      |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2013
Audrey     |   3     |    2    |   4     | 2013

Table TeamInfo:
PlayerName | Team  | Year
Mike       | Team1 | 2014
Mike       | Team2 | 2013
Brian      | Team1 | 2014
Karen      | Team3 | 2014
```

The key points are that I want to sum the values in PlayerEval and CoachEval for all of the names in the PlayerDetails table.  Players may or may not exist in the PlayerEval or CoachEval tables or they could exist but for previous years - I only want values from 2014.
Also display Team info if they exist.  I have wrote a procedure that gets me close, but I usually always missing some of the data.

The Skills in the table above are different in the query below.  Example Skill_1 is BallControl_dribbling, Skill_2 is 1v1_dribbling, etc...

Thanks,Mike

```
Procedure:
declare y int;
declare g int;
declare gender varchar(20);
set y = 1;
set g = 1;

SELECT @x := count(*) from AgeGroups;   # this table just includes a list of ages[U9,U10,U11,U12,U13,U14]

while g < 3 DO
   if (g = 1) then 
      set gender = 'Male';
   else
      set gender = 'FeMale';
   end if;

while y < 8 DO
     SELECT @grade := Grade from AgeGroups where id=y;
     SELECT @v3 := Age from AgeGroups where id=y;
     SELECT @TotalRegistered := count(*) from PlayerDetails WHERE PlayerDetails.Grade = @grade AND PlayerDetails.Gender=gender;

     SELECT PlayerDetails.id,PlayerDetails.PlayerName, PlayerEvals.PlayerName, TeamInfo.NAME,
     PlayerDetails.Gender, PlayerDetails.Grade, 
     round(sum( ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`BallControl_dribbling` , 0 ) + ifnull(`PlayerEvals`.`1v1_dribbling` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`1_Touch_No-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`1_Touch_with-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`Air_No-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`Air_with-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`weighted_pass_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`combination_play_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`crossing_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`chipping_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`placement_shooting` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`awareness_shooting` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`1v1_defense` , 0 ) + ifnull( `PlayerEvals`.`2v2_defense` , 0 ) ) / ( count( `PlayerEvals`.`BallControl_dribbling` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`1v1_dribbling` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`1_Touch_No-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`1_Touch_with-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`Air_No-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`Air_with-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`weighted_pass_passing` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`combination_play_passing` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`crossing_passing` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`chipping_passing` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`placement_shooting` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`awareness_shooting` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`1v1_defense` ) + count( `PlayerEvals`.`2v2_defense` ) ),4) AS Tryout_Average,
     round(sum( ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`BallControl_dribbling` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`1v1_dribbling` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`1_Touch_No-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`1_Touch_with-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`Air_No-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`Air_with-pressure_receiving` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`weighted_pass_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`combination_play_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`crossing_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`chipping_passing` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`placement_shooting` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`awareness_shooting` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`1v1_defense` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`2v2_defense` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`offense_heading`, 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`defense_heading` , 0 ) + ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`5v5_teamdefense` , 0 ) ) / ( count( `CoachEvals`.`BallControl_dribbling` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`1v1_dribbling` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`1_Touch_No-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`1_Touch_with-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`Air_No-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`Air_with-pressure_receiving` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`weighted_pass_passing` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`combination_play_passing` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`crossing_passing` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`chipping_passing` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`placement_shooting` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`awareness_shooting` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`1v1_defense` ) + count( `CoachEvals`.`2v2_defense` ) +count(`CoachEvals`.`offense_heading`) +count(`CoachEvals`.`defense_heading`) + count( `CoachEvals`.`5v5_teamdefense`) + count(`CoachEvals`.`offense_heading`) + count(`CoachEvals`.`defense_heading`) ),4) AS Coach_Average, 
    round(sum( ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`GeneralAttitude`, 0)) / (   count(`CoachEvals`.`GeneralAttitude`) ),4) AS Coach_General_Attitude, 
    round(sum( ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`AttendsPractice`, 0)) / ( count(`CoachEvals`.`AttendsPractice`) ),4) AS Coach_Attends_Practice,
    round(sum( ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`AbilitytoLearn`, 0)) / ( count(`CoachEvals`.`AbilitytoLearn`) ),4) AS Coach_Ability_to_Learn,
    round(sum( ifnull( `CoachEvals`.`Goalie`, 0) ) / ( count(`CoachEvals`.`Goalie`) ),4) AS Coach_Goalie
     FROM `PlayerDetails` 
     LEFT JOIN PlayerEvals ON PlayerDetails.PlayerName=PlayerEvals.PlayerName
     AND (PlayerEvals.Date=@try1 OR PlayerEvals.Date=@try2)
     LEFT JOIN CoachEvals ON (PlayerDetails.PlayerName=CoachEvals.PlayerName)
     LEFT JOIN TeamInfo ON (PlayerDetails.PlayerName = TeamInfo.PlayerName)
     WHERE PlayerEvals.Date is NULL or (PlayerEvals.Date=@try1 OR PlayerEvals.Date=@try2)
      AND PlayerDetails.Gender = gender
      AND PlayerDetails.Grade = @grade
      group by PlayerDetails.Gender,PlayerDetails.PlayerName
      order by Tryout_Average;

      set y = y + 1;
   END WHILE;
   set g = g + 1;
   set y = 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

Expected output:

```
Playername    TEAM NAME    Gender    Grade      Tryout_Average    Coach_Average 
Mike           Team1        Male     3rd Grade    2.07               3 
Brian          NULL         Male     4th Grade    3                  3 
Steve          NULL         Male     4th Grade    NULL               NULL 
Audrey         NULL         Female   3rd Grade    NULL               NULL 
Karen          NULL         Female   5th Grade    3.25               3
```

the averages in Tryout_Average and Coach_Average are calculated in the query.  I use sum of Skill-1, Skill-2, Skill-3 if they are not NULL and then divide by the count of the values.

Comment: Can you show the expected results based on the data you gave? Preferably in an [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Having issue getting it into sqlfiddle.  But the output should be similar to this.                                      `Playername TEAM NAME Gender Grade  Tryout_Average Coach_Average 
Mike  Team1  Male 3rd Grade 2.07  3  

Brian  NULL  Male 4th Grade 3  3
Steve  NULL  Male 4th Grade NULL  NULL

Audrey  NULL  Female 3rd Grade NULL  NULL

Karen  NULL  Female 5th Grade 3.25  3
`

Comment: thanks for that. I would edit the question and add it in a nicer format for others to read. I will take a look at it and see what i can do, if anything

Comment: Also, will you explain how you got the average values

Comment: Add the expected output to the question.  Thanks again for any help.  The averages are calculated in the query by using the sum statement and ifnull statement then divide it by the count statement   So it looks like this:  sum (ifnull(Skill-1,0) + ifnull(skill-2,0) + ifnull(skill-3,0) / Count (skill-1)